# (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Trying to access asp.net configuration and get this  '(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)'

already tried these solutions: http://forums.asp.net/t/1396682.aspx?Could+not+establish+a+connection+to+the+database+for+asp+net+configuration+

http://forums.iis.net/t/1163032.aspx?
Provider+Management+error+of+asp+net+configaration+in+asp+net

[Asp.Net membership via ASP.NET Website Administrator Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423515/asp-net-membership-via-asp-net-website-administrator-tool)

**UPDATE**: I took a look in the SQL Server Configuration Manager and selected SQL server Service and it had a error "The remote procedure call failed.[0x800706be]" What I don't get is what caused this, was it the web.config or the sql server itself. To my knowledge the SQL server file is still in one place and that's it, I made a Connection string in VS to check if everything is OK and the server contained all the tables needed and everything was alright so I don't get the catch here.

here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->
<configuration>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<system.web>
<roleManager enabled="true" />

<authentication mode="Forms" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionStringTest" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Project.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=30;Application Name=EntityFramework"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ASPNETDB" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=30;Application Name=EntityFramework"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
</appSettings>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  <providers>
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
</configuration>
```